# Add st, nd, rd and th (ordinal) suffix (e.g. July 20th, 2021) in "Send an email (V2)" action - Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, power-automate, ms-flow

Is it possible to add suffix (ordinal) in email body of "**Send an email (V2)**" action in power automate?

Expected Date format - "**July 20th, 2021**".

I am trying to add suffix "st, nd, rd and th" in date/time format.

If it is possible, can someone please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add the suffixes to the numbers between 1-31. These are the steps:

Initialize variable Date_Suffix and assig it to **th**:

[image]

Add a compose action to extract a day number using a `dayOfMonth()` function:

[image]

Add the following 3 conditions that overwrite the Date_Suffix's value:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally, get the user-friendly date format using this formula:

```
@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MMMM d')}@{variables('Date_Suffix')},  @{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyy')}
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

Could we do it in fewer steps? Yes, but I am just showing a quick and dirty approach that is easy to read and understand.